# Possible post - measurement states for Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[|00\rangle + |11\rangle]$

Tags: entanglement, measurement, textbook-and-exercises, bell-basis

This is in reference to page 241 of Introduction to classical and quantum computing by Thomas.G Wong.

The author starts off with a Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[|00\rangle + |11\rangle]$.

In trying to illustrate the violation of Bell - CHSH inequality, he propose 4 pairs of measurement basis: They are basis X, Z for Alice and basis A, A' for Bob.

Base on this, there are 4 possible measurement combination: XA, ZA, XA', ZA'.

For each combination above, N measurement outcomes may be obtained.

The author mentioned that there is some probability for which Alice has a post measurement state of $|0\rangle$ and Bob has a post measurement state of $|1\rangle$; there is also some probability Alice has a post measurement state of $|1\rangle$ and Bob a post measurement state of $|0\rangle$.

How is this possible? My understanding is that regardless the measurement basis used for measurement, the Bell state given qualifies to only collapse to the state $|00\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$. I have been trying to figure this out the entire day so some illumination is appreciated.

Comment: that is true if both parties measure on the same basis. That is not the case in the classical CHSH case: note that Alice and Bob use different measurement bases (A and A' are not the same as X and Z)

Comment: Indeed even without playing the CHSH game, one of Alice or Bob could apply an X gate to their qubit, which leads to a state as $1/\sqrt 2(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$, and Alice and Bob’s qubits are opposite to each other when measured in the computational basis.